# Quicker alternative to AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, audio

I have an app in which the frame rate slows down dramatically when a sound is played. I am using `AVAudioPlayer` to play these sounds, and there are many sounds being played within short spaces of time. These sounds are only a matter of kilobytes. Is there an alternative way to play these sounds with much lower performance costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Read the audio files into raw PCM arrays during while the app is starting up, and asynchronously.  Then use the Audio Unit API, and copy the samples to RemoteIO Audio Unit buffer callbacks, directly, or via an audio mixer.  Extremely low performance overhead for pre-mixed and/or non-overlapped audio.  A tiny amount more overhead for some small amount of audio mixing.

Comment: Pardon the 'noobiness,' but I am not particularly experienced when it comes to audio programming. Is there a document I could read to learn this technique, or could you perhaps give me a quick run through of how I might go about doing this?

Comment: There's an entire book on the topic.  "Core Audio" IIRC.  It's not a quick subject area.

Comment: @hotpaw2 - Do you have any sample of it? Thanks.